# How to pass a function as a Prop in Yew?

Tags: rust, yew

**I simply want to pass a function to one of my children through their props so it can be used there.**

Here's the code I have now

```rust
use log::info;
use yew::html::onclick::Event;
use yew::prelude::*;


// Create Properties with the function I want to use
#[derive(yew::Properties, PartialEq)]
pub struct MyProps {
    pub do_this: fn(Event) -> (),
    pub val: String,
}

#[function_component(Base)]
pub fn home(props: &MyProps) -> Html {
    let do_this_func = props.do_this.clone();
    html! {
        <button onclick={move |e: Event|  do_this_func(e)}>  {"press me"} </button>
    }
}

// Pass the function
#[function_component(App)]
pub fn app() -> Html {
    fn do_this_func(s: Event) {
        info!("clicked from my func")
    }
    html! {
        <Base do_this={do_this_func} val={"hello".to_string()} />
    }
}

fn main() {
    wasm_logger::init(wasm_logger::Config::default());
    yew::start_app::<App>();
}
```

If I remove `do_this` and just pass in `val` the compiler errors go away. I'd expect that just specifying the type on the props would be enough, but it's not.

Here are the compiler errors I get.

```
   Compiling yew-app v0.1.0 (/Users/sasacocic/development/tinkering/yew-app)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `fn(MouseEvent) {do_this_func}: IntoPropValue<fn(MouseEvent)>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:25:24
   |
25 |         <Base do_this={do_this_func} val={"hello".to_string()} />
   |               -------  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `IntoPropValue<fn(MouseEvent)>` is not implemented for `fn(MouseEvent) {do_this_func}`
   |               |
   |               required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `IntoPropValue<T>`:
             <&'static str as IntoPropValue<AttrValue>>
             <&'static str as IntoPropValue<Classes>>
             <&'static str as IntoPropValue<Option<AttrValue>>>
             <&'static str as IntoPropValue<Option<String>>>
             <&'static str as IntoPropValue<String>>
             <&T as IntoPropValue<Option<T>>>
             <&T as IntoPropValue<T>>
             <Classes as IntoPropValue<AttrValue>>
           and 6 others
note: required by a bound in `MyPropsBuilder::<MyPropsBuilderStep_missing_required_prop_do_this>::do_this`
  --> src/main.rs:5:10
   |
5  | #[derive(yew::Properties, PartialEq)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `MyPropsBuilder::<MyPropsBuilderStep_missing_required_prop_do_this>::do_this`
6  | pub struct MyProps {
7  |     pub do_this: fn(Event) -> (),
   |         ------- required by a bound in this
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `yew::Properties` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I could implement the `IntoPropValue` trait, but that seems a bit extra for just passing a function to child. Is there an simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple solution is to use yew's `Callback`. Here's how you can do it with the above example.

The code does a few things differently from the above

1. it does `use yew::Callback`
2. it changes `fn(Event) -> ()` in `MyProps` to `Callback<Event>`
3. it creates a `Callback` by doing `Callback::from(do_this_func)`
4. to call the actual function passed it uses `emit` i.e. `do_this_func.emit(e)`

the complete code for this is below and commented

```rust
use log::info;
use yew::html::onclick::Event;
use yew::prelude::*;
use yew::Callback; // import Callback

#[derive(yew::Properties, PartialEq)]
pub struct MyProps {
    pub do_this: Callback<Event>, // change fn(Event) -> () to Callback<Event>
    pub val: String,
}

#[function_component(Base)]
pub fn home(props: &MyProps) -> Html {
    let do_this_func = props.do_this.clone();

    html! {
        // calls the emit method on the Callback 
        <button onclick={move |e: Event|  do_this_func.emit(e)}>  {"press me"} </button>
    }
}

#[function_component(App)]
pub fn app() -> Html {
    fn do_this_func(s: Event) {
        info!("clicked from my func")
    }


    // creates the callback with Callback::from
    let cb = Callback::from(do_this_func);
    html! {
        <Base do_this={cb} val={"hello".to_string()} />
    }
}

fn main() {
    wasm_logger::init(wasm_logger::Config::default());
    yew::start_app::<App>();
}
```